# Comments using forward slashes

Tags: status-norepro, comments, discussion

When did comments switch to using forward slashes rather than hyphens?

What was the rationale behind this change? Personally, I find hyphens more logical

#### EDIT:

[image: Screenie with obligatory red freehand circles]

Comment: What comments are you referring to?

Comment: All comments, on all StackExchange sites. The slash here ->

Comment: you mean the dash there? I see no slash.

Comment: @Eric That's a hyphen to me.

Comment: Or do you mean the pencil edit icon on the far right? which might look like a forward slash on some screens?

Comment: screen shot of what you are seeing I think please

Comment: @Eric More specifically it's an `&ndash;`

Comment: Ooh. Very strange how you're getting different results. Picture to follow

Comment: What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Chrome/Windows XP

Comment: @Eric More specifically, **What font are you using?**

Comment: Arial, as described in the site's CSS. Very strange. Chrome bug, methinks. The source code is correct

Comment: Are you using a beta version of Chrome?

Comment: Yes, but I thought that at present the beta is the same build as the standard release.

Comment: I use the Dev version of Chrome and I see the dashes just fine.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce the issue in jsfiddle...

Comment: Can you see this character? "–" It should be the hyphen.

Comment: Viewing the page's source code, it's using `'&ndash;'` as the separator.  Does it appear the same to you in the source?  Do you see slashes when you see pages from other sites that use `'&ndash;'`?  I don't think it would be a font issue, either a browser or regional settings (in windows).

Comment: Very odd. After a restart, everything is displaying properly... And yes, viewing the source code does indeed reveal an '`ndash;`'. Sorry waiwai933, but I can no longer test your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm in Linux using Dev Chrome and normal Chromium and can't repro
[image: Chrome]

Maybe its specific to XP's dev version?

Comment: This should've been a comment :)

Comment: @badp, not with a screenshot

Comment: What @badp meant to say is, it doesn't include Freehand Circles, thus the image was unnecessary and it should have been a comment.

Comment: @jjnguy, you could've linked to them. `[link](http://blah/)` works in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your seeing. All the comments I am seeing are showing hyphens (-) between the comment and the name. The following screenshot is from Apple.SE showing hyphens:

[image]

After seeing your screenshot, it looks like your either using a non-standard font which does not support the / or there is a serious bug in the browser version your using.

Comment: Looks the same to me.

Comment: mine doesn't have the red.  should i report a bug?

Comment: @Sam Yes please.

Comment: @Sam: Definitely report a bug! WIthout the red you're unlikely to get anything upvoted on meta!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your cache? Because I don't think what you're seeing is normal, I can't reproduce it in Chrome on Windows XP...

**EDIT**: But I'm not using the beta which I just saw you posted you're using.

Comment: What version number are you running? My beta is 6.0.472.53. That's the same as the standard release, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with the fact that you're using a beta browser. **Beta browsers are not officially supported**. You should report a bug at the Chromium project website.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I have Chrome 7 and no repro.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not using the correct encoding.

Try this: **Wrench menu, Tools, Encoding, Unicode (UTF-8)**.

Comment: If you are using Unicode (UTF-8) the following will look like arrows, not garbage: ←↑↓→